# fetching random rows from an oracle database with CodeIgniter Active Record

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, oracle-call-interface

I want to make a specific query over an Oracle database. I am using CodeIgniter with oci db driver. My query looks something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (select inner_query.*, rownum rnum FROM (SELECT tutor_profiles.id AS "tutor_id", tutor_profiles.full_name AS "full_name", files.file_uri as "file_uri", files.id, count(distinct courses.id) AS "course_count"
FROM tutor_profiles
LEFT JOIN files ON files.id = tutor_profiles.avatar_id
LEFT JOIN courses ON tutor_profiles.id = courses.tutor_id
GROUP BY tutor_profiles.id, tutor_profiles.full_name, files.file_uri, files.id
ORDER BY dbms_random.VALUE) inner_query WHERE rownum <= 4)
```

I am fetching random tutors from the database and join other tables to the result. The problem is I can not generate this query with Active Record.
I get dbms_random.Value error, but when I run this on oracle sql editor it works fine. Anyone know how to generate this query with AR?

Comment: `Note: random ordering is not currently supported in Oracle or MSSQL drivers.`: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html CI's Active Record is not the solution to all things, although I wish it were, of course.

Answer (score 0):

It is the active record library's method order_by() that is escaping the value "dbms_random.VALUE".

I took a look at the library and found the following valid parameters: $orderby, $direction = '', $escape = TRUE

You should instruct the method not to escape your string and the call would look like:

```
$this->db->order_by("dbms_random.VALUE", '', false);
```

Otherwise, you can always execute your query without using the active record library.